# Fibonacci en python

Tags: python, fibonacci

Estoy empezando en Python (llevo apenas unos días aprendiendo y es mi primer lenguaje) y he visto en un video de Joma Tech que enseñaba como hacer la serie de fibonacci con esta función:

```
def fib(n):

    if n==0:
        return 1
    elif n==1:
        return 1
    else:
        return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
```

La cuestión es que él usaba de ide GCC y ponia la `n` en otra pantalla y le salia el numero de fibonacci para esa `n`, pero yo utilizo pycharm y no encuentro la manera de hacer que me pregunte la `n` con un `print int(input("Insertar n:"))` y que el `input` se ponga en la `n` de la función `fib(n)`.
A parte, no entiendo como es posible que para `n=6` le de `13` si seria `(6-1)+(6-2)=9` y luego pone `n=7` y le da `21` si en el `return` tendria que ser `(7-1)+(7-2)=11`

Pd: Si alguien no entiende como ponía él la `n`, en el minuto 10:41 de este vídeo de [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OnXlnd3JB-8&t=684s) sale como hace la función

Comment: da la sensación de que no interpreta bien la serie 
https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sucesi%C3%B3n_de_Fibonacci#Definici%C3%B3n_recursiva

Comment: Como comenta alo Malbarez la función es incorrecta, El return de la primera condición está mal, debe ser  `if n==0:  return 0`. Aparte de esto, te olvidas que no es `(6-1)+(6-2)`, es `fib(6-1) + fib(6-2)`, la función se llama a si misma recursivamente.

Answer (score 8):

En cuanto a la primera duda, en el video no usan "GCC" como IDE, GCC es el compilador de lenguaje C usado para compilar Python en esa máquina, lo que usan en el video de hecho no es un IDE al uso, se trata de la web [Repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/AliceblueVigilantLaws)

En cuanto a las dudas con el código en si, primero de todo la función está mal como se ha comentado, el item 0 de la serie de Fibonacci  es 0 no 1. Si quieres pedir al usuario el número debes usar `input`, que retorna una cadena (en Python 3),  haces un casting a `int` de la misma y lo almacenas en una variable. Llamas a la función con este valor y luego usas `print` para mostrar el resultado, por ejemplo.

```
def fib(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    elif n == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2)

n = int(input("Ingrese el valor 'n': "))
item = fib(n)
print(f"El item {n} de la serie de Fibonacci es {item}")
```

En cuanto a lo de la entrada por la terminal en PyCharm, en el video hacen uso en realidad de lo que se conoce como intérprete interactivo. Pycharm por defecto no ejecuta el intérprete interactivo tras ejecutar el código, pero puedes hacer algo para conseguirlo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
En la ventana que se abre ve al entry `Interpreter Options`  y añade `-i`, y acepta.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando ejecutes el script (botón "play" verde), tras ejecutarse se abrirá el intérprete interactivo, un ejemplo de ejecución:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

PyCharm posiblemente sea el IDE más completo para Python que hay ahora mismo, no obstante su funcionalidad con el intérprete interactivo deja bastante que desear en mi opinión. Si estás aprendiendo, creo que hay IDEs mejores, sin tantas funcionalidad que por ahora no vas a usar, pero mucho más simples de usar para los scripts que irás creando por ahora. El  IDLE que viene con el propio Python es muy buena opción para estos primeros pasos, ejecutando todo en una ventana con el intérprete interactivo, muy útil cuando se está aprendiendo.

Dicho esto, `fib(6)` es 8, porque no es `(6 - 1) + (6 - 2)` como comentas, la sentencia es `fib(6 - 1) + fib(6 - 2)`, es decir, hay dos llamadas recursivas a la función `fib(5)`  y  `fib(4)`.

La recursión puede resultar algo liosa de entender, vamos a partir de un ejemplo más simple, `fib(3)`:

1. Se llama a `fib(3)`, este llega por el condicional a ejecutar `fib(3 - 1) + fib(3 - 2)`.
2. Al evaluar dicha suma, primero se ejecuta `fib(3 - 1)`, esta llamada a la función (`fib(2)`) se ejecuta igual que la primera, llega a su `return fib(2 - 1) + fib(2 - 2)`.
3. Pasa igual que antes, primero se evalúa el lado izquierdo, `fib(2 - 1)`, esta llamada a la función (`fib(1)`) termina con `return 1`. Retorno que vuelve a la llamada del paso 2 que quedó a a la espera.
4. Ahora la función del paso 2 tiene `1 + fib(2 - 2)`, pasa a evaluar la parte derecha. Ejecuta `fib(2 - 2)` que retorna 0, por lo que la función del paso 2 tiene `1 + 0` y por fin puede retornar, devolviendo `1` a la función del paso 1.
5. Ahora la función del paso 1 tiene `1 + fib(3 - 2)`, ejecuta por tanto `fib(3 - 2)`, es decir `fib(1)`, que le retorna `1`. Ahora la función del paso 1 tiene `1 + 1` y retorna por fin, de forma que `fib(3)` es 2.

Observa que se genera un árbol de llamadas que crece desde la raiz (`fib(3)`) y en el que cada función para poder completarse y retornar ha de esperar a que lo hagan las llamadas que ella misma hace, por lo que  el retorno es siempre en la dirección contraria a las llamada, de las hojas a la raiz. Es decir, la llamada a la función que tu realizas es la última en completarse y poder retornar. Esto se vuelve cada vez más complejo  a medida que aumenta `n`, para `fib(6)` tenemos :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En rojo se indica el orden en que cada llamada es realizada, el orden de retorno es diferente como se explicaba arriba, en este caso el orden de retorno es:

> 6 - 7 - 5 - 8 - 4 - 10 - 11 - 9 - 3 - 14 - 15 - 13 - 16 - 
>   12 - 2 - 20 - 21 - 19 - 22 - 18 - 24 - 25 - 23 - 17 - 1

Nada mal, para solo generar el 6º elemento de la sucesión tenemos 25 llamadas a la función `fib`. Para `fib(41)` que es 165580141 tenemos nada menos que
535828591 llamadas a `fib` si no me equivoco...

> **Nota:** no se se si usa Python 3 como en el vídeo o Python 2, no obstante, si estás aprendiendo te aconsejo olvidarte de Python 2, el soporte para la rama 2 termina en Enero del 2020 y existen diferencias importantes entre ambas ramas.

Para terminar, podemos usar la función generadora ([ver entrada en Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sucesi%C3%B3n_de_Fibonacci)) para obtener el item `i` de la sucesión eficientemente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
from math import sqrt


# Número áureo 
PHI = (1 + sqrt(5)) / 2


def fib(n: int) -> int:
    if n < 2:
        return n
    return int((PHI**n / sqrt(5)) + 0.5)
```

Comment: Buenísima respuesta!

Comment: Pero como es que no hace falta un bucle para que se vaya almacenando la nueva n todo el rato? Porque por intuicion, lo que deduzco es que cuando acabe el else saldra en la consola el numero procedente del return que pertenece al else, es decir, fib(n-1) + fib(n-2) pero con la n que se ha escrito en la consola no?

Answer (score 3):

En python 2.7 sería algo asi:

`fibo.py`

```
def fib(n):
    if n==0:
        return 0
    elif n==1:
        return 1
    elif n==2:
        return 1
    else:
        return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)

n = int(input("Insertar n:"))
print "n={} fib({})={}".format(n, n, fib(n))
```

---

`$ python fibo.py`

```
Insertar n:7
n=7 fib(7)=13
```

y la confirmación https://www.numberempire.com/fibonaccinumbers.php?number=7

Answer (score 0):

Esta versión que he hecho da un mejor uso de la recursividad para la serie de fibonacci:

```
def fibonacci(n,a=0,b=1):
    while n!=0:
        return fibonacci(n-1,b,a+b)
    return a
```